# What is the number after the class name in llvn type?

Tags: c++, llvm, clang++

I got function types in LLVM pass by getFunctionType(), when I print them, the function type contains something like: `(%"class.xalanc_1_8::ReusableArenaBlock.10232"*)`.

The former part is the class name `class.xalanc_1_8::ReusableArenaBlock`, what about the number. Some of them contain multiple numbers. I'm wondering about the usage of the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frontend (which typically parses a source code language) needs to create LLVM types with unique names. Most frontends use type names and other strings from the source code to construct the IR type's name, but sometimes that's not (guaranteed to be) unique. Appending a number is the normal way to achieve uniqueness.

In fact appending a number it is what LLVM itself does if you create certain types or many other things, and there's no error except that your requested name is already taken.

It's not the only way to avoid conflicts. My own code adds line numbers from the source code in some cases (not for types, though).

Comment: Thanks. I got it. And one more question: Does that mean the class declarations for the same class (in C++ language) are regarded as different types in LLVM since LLVM uses SSA? So the C++ may regard them are the same class, but LLVM does not directly if without further analysis?

Comment: No, they're the same, because clang takes care to generate the same name for the same class always. Making that work correctly is finicky, but clang succeeds.